# Elegant way to correctly index a Dataframe after Subsetting

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dummy dataframe with two columns:

```
set.seed(666)
df = data.frame(group = rep(c(-1,1), times = 5, each = 1),
                values = runif(10))

   group     values
1     -1 0.77436849
2      1 0.19722419
3     -1 0.97801384
4      1 0.20132735
5     -1 0.36124443
6      1 0.74261194
7     -1 0.97872844
8      1 0.49811371
9     -1 0.01331584
10     1 0.25994613
```

I want to find the row index of the maximum value from group "1" in the original dataframe. Applying `which.max()` after subsetting the dataframe will return the wrong row:

```
which.max(df[df[,1]==1,2]) #returns '3'
```

As a workaround I did the following:

```
sdf = df[df[,1] == 1,] # subset of dataframe that keeps row names
rownames(sdf[which.max(sdf[,2]),]) # returns '6'
```

Which does return the correct row index from the original dataframe. However I feel there must be an easier, more elegant solution but can't think of anything else myself. Any ideas?

I feel really stupid for asking this question but it seems I'm overlooking something very simple.

Comment: If the groups are really `-1` and `1`, and the values are really all positive, then `which.max(df$group * df$value)`.

Comment: @MartinMorgan the groups are not really `-1` and `1` but thanks for the comment, that's pretty clever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `match()` to create a logical vector with `1` being the group of interest, and `NA` for all other groups. Use it as a filter on values,

```
which.max(match(df$group, 1) * df$values)
```

`match(df$group, 1)` (for any value, not just `1`) returns a vector of NA or 1. Multiplying `df$values` returns either NA or the original value. `which.max()` select the maximum of the original values, ignoring (in the calculation of the maximum) the NA values.

Answer (score 2):

This is the tidyverse way:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(666)
df = data.frame(group = rep(c(-1,1), times = 5, each = 1),
                values = runif(10))

df %>%
  mutate(row_number = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  # descending sorting
  arrange(-values) %>%
  # pick first e.g. maximum
  slice(1) %>%
  select(group, row_number)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   group row_number
#>   <dbl>      <int>
#> 1    -1          7
#> 2     1          6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a base R approach, but it's also not very elegant.

```
which(df[, 2] == max(df[which(df[, 1] == 1), 2]))
[1] 6
```

### Input

```
df
   group     values
1     -1 0.77436849
2      1 0.19722419
3     -1 0.97801384
4      1 0.20132735
5     -1 0.36124443
6      1 0.74261194
7     -1 0.97872844
8      1 0.49811371
9     -1 0.01331584
10     1 0.25994613
```